# Magento blank pages after grunt clean

Tags: javascript, node.js, magento, gruntjs, less

I'm working in developer mode (Magento 2) and I've just done the following:

```
grunt clean

grunt exec:myTheme

grunt less:myTheme

grunt watch
```

Grunt is watching any updated less files but when I got to load the page its just a blank page. I also can't access the admin side either.

Any ideas as to what I've done wrong or if you need me to post certain files I will. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting read/write permissions in the root of the magento file

```
chown -R :www-data .
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```